# How to access PluginDependenciesSpecScope while create custom gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am creating a **custom gradle plugin** and I need to add a pluginId with version

in .gradle files we do it like

```
plugins{
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.7.0-1.0.6"
}
//plugins block has PluginDependenciesSpecScope
```

I want to achieve the same while extending from Plugin, not sure how to access `PluginDependenciesSpecScope` to achieve the same

```
class ComposePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.apply {
            apply("com.google.devtools.ksp")
            //not getting option to add version 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the "correct" way to do it since official documentation is lacking here, but I was able to get around this by declaring it inside my project-level `build.gradle.kts` file as such:

```kotlin
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.google.devtools.ksp:com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin:1.7.0-1.0.6")
  }
}
```

From there, I can just "apply" the plugin inside my custom Gradle plugin code as such:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.apply("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    }
}
```